# Meagre sets have empty interior-A false statement.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, baire-category

Suppose $A$ is a meagre set i.e. a set of first category.Then $A=\large\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} $$A_n$,where each $A_n$ is nowhere dense.Now $A^o=(\large \cup_n A_n)^o\subset\large \cup_n A_n^o=\phi$ as $A_n^o\subset (\bar A_n)^o=\phi$.Thus we are done.Is this proof correct?
Then we can also prove Baire Category that complete metric spaces are not meagre.By showing that if $X$ is meagre,then $X^o=\phi$,which is a contradiction,but where do we require completeness,am I making mistake?Is this not true $(\large \cup_n A_n)^o\subset\large \cup_n A_n^o$.

Comment: @Reveillark Yes we cannot conclude that meagre sets have empty interior as take $\mathbb Q$ with usual metric,its interior in itself is $\mathbb Q$ but it is meagre.

Comment: @Reveillark Let me make another thing clear that comeagre implies second category but not conversely for example $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Reveillark Your example doesn't work. The interior of $\cup_n A_n$ is also empty.  (As I understand $\subset$ only means $\subseteq$ in OP's work).

Comment: Ah yes, you are, of course, right. I was taking closures in my mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A_1$ is the set of all rational numbers, $A_2$ is the set of all irrational numbers, and $A_n$ is the empty set for $n>2$ the  interrior of $\cup_n A_n $ is the entire real line whereas $A_n^{0} $ is empty for each $n$.